# Why do drones look different from common airplanes?

Tags: aircraft-design, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, airplane

In this video is shown [Top 5 Military Drone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFmw718WCvY). As we may see, the shape looks different than usual airplanes. My concern is especially with the tail. Normally we know that the tail is vertical. But from those 5, the tails are V-shaped or inverse-V.

I know this is probably a trivial thing for some of you. But that is quite important, as that way is used in most pioneer drones.

Comment: A couple of related questions on V-tails: [What are the advantages and disadvantages of ruddervators?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-ruddervators) and [What is the difference between the V-shape tail and the straight tail on the Beechcraft Bonanza?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9504/what-is-the-difference-between-the-v-shape-tail-and-the-straight-tail-on-the-bee)

Comment: dears, apologize for the duplicate posting. i do don't intent to do so. i have search before i asked this question, especially the articles which shown during writing the question. later i will be more careful to avoid such mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious difference between a drone or UAV or UCAV, and a manned aircraft is that it has no pilot, and therefore no cockpit structure. In practical terms this means that the minimum cross sectional area of the fuselage is potentially smaller, and the aircraft can be smaller overall than a manned aircraft with similar range/payload capability. In general terms, the smaller the aircraft, the greater the significance of the pilot, ejection seat and cockpit structure as a percentage of the takeoff weight, and the greater the impact they will have on the overall structural design of the aircraft.

Comment: If the reason is due to no pilot, the the "head" should be same size with the fuselage. But as we may see, some of them have bulde on their head, room which supposed to be place of pilot. But actually my concern is more to the tail which the shape is V or inverted-V shape. Why not like common airplane?

Comment: The Beechcraft Bonanza is one classic light aircraft design with a V tail. Replacing three control surfaces with two saves weight.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an inverse-V tail shape is used to protect a pusher propeller from striking the ground.

Many drones have high-aspect ratio wings (long and narrow, like a sailplane) for maximum efficiency and endurance, at some cost to maneuverability.

Comment: I can understand if it is intended to protect the propeller from striking the ground. Yes, I have guess so, too. But my question is, why V-shaped or inverted-V shape? V-shape means, there are two tails rather than only one. I have more concern about the tail shape.

Comment: What's wrong with the V-tail? Bonanza had a great run of V-tail airplanes starting way back in 1947, and now the FS50 single engine jet from Cirrus is a V-tail. I don't understand what your great concern is.